# Transparent JFrame

Tags: java, swing, jframe, transparency

I have a JFrame that holds a JPanel. I want to make the frame completely transparent and the panel slightly transparent.

I'm using the following code to do so:

```
frame.setBackground(new Color(0, 0, 0, 0));
panel.setBackground(new Color(51, 51, 51, 190));
```

The desired effect is achieved, however, when I make the JFrame transparent using this method it distorts all of the other components.

The following image demonstrates this better than I can explain.

[image]

On the left is an example with no transparency and the text appears clearly. On the right the panel and the frame are set using the code above, and the text is distorted.

What am I missing?

Comment: Don't use alpha based colours with components (works okay for the frame), instead, you need to use setOpaque(false) and override the panel's paintComponent method and fake it

Comment: For [example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32574630/set-jframe-background-transparent-but-show-contents/32575548#32575548) and [example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29026419/using-frame-setbackground0-255-0-0-doesnt-work-with-linux/29028825#29028825)

Comment: Maybe font anti-aliasing to be explicitly set off, when MadProgrammer's solution does not help. Before calling super.paintComponent or so `Graphics2D.setRenderingHint(        RenderingHints.KEY_TEXT_ANTIALIASING,         RenderingHints.VALUE_TEXT_ANTIALIAS_OFF);`

Comment: This only occurs when I apply the color to the frame, and it only happens when the transparency is less than 255. Whether or not I apply it to the panel, the text still distorts. I can use frame.setBackground(new Color(0, 0, 0, 255)) and it's fine. I can use panel.setBackground(new Color(0, 0, 0, 0)) and it's fine. As soon as I make the frame transparent (using frame.setBackground(new Color(0, 0, 0, 254)), say) it distorts.

Comment: This is actually a JDialog, not a JFrame - sorry. What does that change?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> however, when I make the JFrame transparent using this method it distorts all of the other components.

The problem is Swing thinks the component is opaque so it doesn't paint the background first so you get painting artifacts.

Check out [Background With Transparency](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/05/31/backgrounds-with-transparency/). It has two simple solutions:

1. paint the background yourself
2. use a wrapper container to do the painting for you