# How to make the JFrame contentPane transparent but the JFrame visible?

Tags: java, swing, jframe, contentpane

I wanted to know how to make the JFrame's  contentPane transparent but the JFrame visible. I saw many pages but all showed on how to make the JFrame border visible but the contentPane visible.

I tried using `setOpacity()` but that requires the JFrame to be `undecorated`.

Are there any methods that I can achieve this?

Comment: Maybe this will help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32843038/transparent-jframe. If not search the site for other example. Keywords might be "transparent jframe".

Comment: Swing was not designed to paint with transparent backgrounds.  You cannot create a transparent contentPane.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Swing was not designed to paint with transparent backgrounds. You cannot create a transparent contentPane.  However, you can fake a transparent background.

Here's a screenshot showing a fake transparent background.  I cropped and reduced the image by 50% to get it to display in this answer.

[image]

So, how did I do this?

I took a snapshot of the background and painted the background on the `JPanel`.

This only works if you **do not change the background** while you're displaying your `JFrame`.  If you change the background by opening or closing any other applications,  this fake **will not work**.

You can move the `JFrame` around.  Do not move the JFrame close to the edge of the screen, or you'll ruin the illusion.

Iconifying and deiconifying the `JFrame` works, but the illusion becomes obvious.

You can resize, maximize, and restore the `JFrame`.

It requires a lot of code to make this fake work properly.

Here's the complete runnable code.  I made all the additional classes inner classes so I could post this code as one block.

```
import java.awt.AWTException;
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.Point;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.awt.Robot;
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import java.awt.event.ComponentAdapter;
import java.awt.event.ComponentEvent;
import java.awt.event.WindowAdapter;
import java.awt.event.WindowEvent;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class TransparentJPanelView implements Runnable {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new TransparentJPanelView());
    }
    
    private DrawingPanel drawingPanel;
    
    private JFrame frame;
    
    private TransparentJPanelModel model;
    
    public TransparentJPanelView() {
        this.model = new TransparentJPanelModel();
        this.drawingPanel = new DrawingPanel(model);
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        this.frame = new JFrame("Fake Transparent JPanel");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        
        frame.addComponentListener(new FrameComponentListener(this, model));
        FrameListener listener = new FrameListener(this, model);
        frame.addWindowListener(listener);
        frame.addWindowFocusListener(listener);
        frame.addWindowStateListener(listener);

        frame.add(drawingPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
    
    public void repaint() {
        drawingPanel.repaint();
    }
    
    public JFrame getFrame() {
        return frame;
    }

    public class DrawingPanel extends JPanel {

        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
        
        private TransparentJPanelModel model;
        
        public DrawingPanel(TransparentJPanelModel model) {
            this.model = model;
            this.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
            this.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(600, 300));
            
            JButton button = new JButton("Click me");
            this.add(button);
        }
        
        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            
            Point point = new Point(this.getLocation()); 
            SwingUtilities.convertPointToScreen(point, this); 
            
            Image image = model.getSubImage(point.x, point.y, getWidth(), getHeight());
            g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, this);
        }
        
    }
    
    public class FrameComponentListener extends ComponentAdapter {
        
        private final TransparentJPanelView view;
        
        private final TransparentJPanelModel model;
        
        public FrameComponentListener(TransparentJPanelView view, 
                TransparentJPanelModel model) {
            this.view = view;
            this.model = model;
        }

        @Override
        public void componentResized(ComponentEvent event) {
            view.repaint();
        }

        @Override
        public void componentMoved(ComponentEvent event) {
            view.repaint();
        }

    }
    
    public class FrameListener extends WindowAdapter { 

        private final TransparentJPanelView view;
        
        private final TransparentJPanelModel model;
        
        public FrameListener(TransparentJPanelView view, 
                TransparentJPanelModel model) {
            this.view = view;
            this.model = model;
        }
        
        @Override
        public void windowDeiconified(WindowEvent event) {
            model.setBackground();
            view.repaint();
        }
        
    }
    
    public class TransparentJPanelModel {
        
        private BufferedImage background;
        
        private final Rectangle screenRect;
        
        private final Robot robot;
        
        public TransparentJPanelModel() {
            this.robot = createRobot();
            this.screenRect = new Rectangle(
                    Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize());
            setBackground();
        }
        
        private Robot createRobot() {
            Robot robot = null;
            try {
                robot = new Robot();
            } catch (AWTException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return robot;
        }

        public void setBackground() {
            this.background = robot.createScreenCapture(screenRect);
        }
        
        public Image getSubImage(int x, int y, int width, int height) {
            if (x < 0) {
                x = 0;
                width = Math.min(width, screenRect.width);
            }
            
            if (y < 0) {
                y = 0;
                height = Math.min(height, screenRect.height);
            }
            
            if (x + width > screenRect.width) {
                width = screenRect.width - x;
            }
            
            if (y + height > screenRect.height) {
                height = screenRect.height - y;
            }
            
            return background.getSubimage(x, y, width, height);
        }
        
    }
    
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `setVisible(false)` method for each element that is inside that `JFrame`. You use this in the `intialize()` method. Once you want them to be shown (for example after some button is clicked) than you will use the same method `setVisible(true)`.

Comment: The question is about making the contentPane itself transparent not the elements in that

Comment: So according to you the required is `jframe.getContentPane().setVisible(true)`??

Comment: If you want to set contentPane transparant you need to go with ```jframe.getContentPane().setVisible(false);```
This will make the contentPane unvisible.

Comment: i tried that but didn't work out.